# How to improve this proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was doing these two propositions and I do not feel 100% sure about them so I was wondering if I could get any help or advice. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: For the purpose of this forum, the first improvement would be to *type* it.

Comment: There's a chance that your image not be available in the future. To ensure that your question is here to stay, type it down. You may want to consult this page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference on how to format you question in LaTeX style.

Comment: Formatting aside, your proofs look very okay to me. I like how you use words as well to explain what you're doing.

Comment: Is this correct?

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x| < |y|$ if and only if $x^2 < y^2$.

Multiplying $|x| < |y|$ by $|x|$ we get $|x^2| < |xy|$.

Multiplying $|x| < |y|$ by $|y|$ we get $|xy| < |y^2|$.

Both of them together imply that $x^2 < y^2$.